# How to save a string containing coma in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to store the following data that comes from javascript into mysql using php.

`point: Good, Not Bad, Fair, Fine, Average`

If I put quote around the string, it would be like below:

`point: 'Good, Not Bad', 'Fair', 'Fine', 'Average'`

When I used php `explode(',', $_POST['point'])`, it becomes:

```
'Good', 'Not Bad', 'Fair', 'Fine', 'Average'`
```

But I want the string to be:

```
'Good, Not Bad', 'Fair', 'Fine', 'Average'`
```

after I explode.

My html form is inside a loop:

```
<textrea name="point[]" id="point"></textrea>
```

Edited:

The result of `explode(',',$_POST['point']);` and `str_getcsv($_POST['point'], ",", "'")` are exactly the same. They do not output the expected result.

Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The json_encode also not works.

Comment: Dont save with coma, use different symbol like Good, Not Bad#Fair etc.. Or create a table and store one by one. Other way, store as a json array. [{'Good, Not Bad'}, {'Fair'}] etc... If you have to save with comma, replace all comas with '#' etc... in point[] input, before the save.. And when you get them again, replace # with comma after explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using comma seperated values, you can use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$resultArray = str_getcsv( $_POST['point'] , ",", "'");
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Good, Not Bad
    [1] => Fair
    [2] => Fine
    [3] => Average
)
```

[Working Example is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/742b24a8e3695b55c757367ecd29eeeb6746e424)

if you want it in string format : Simply use

```
echo "'".implode("', '", $resultArray)."'";
```

will give you `'Good, Not Bad', 'Fair', 'Fine', 'Average'` As described [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be69a7daf7d8c7cd3bd69b2a349a1409c21debbe)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please look at this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/742b24a8e3695b55c757367ecd29eeeb6746e424

Comment: I have given you a working link example. Please execute the code. It is working.

Comment: `var point= $("textarea[id='point']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();` this point is sent to the server. I tried it with your example but it is not working. Thanks for your help.